# No overload matches delegate when creating custom event for a WinForm application

Tags: c#, events, delegates

I am learning to make a WinForm with c# and I am new to the concept of delegate. After some research on the Internet, it seems that this error arises from inconsistent between the delegate and EventHandler. but they seem fine to me, at least EventArgs definitions are the same. Please tell me what goes wrong.

I've placed this inside the Form1 constructor:

```
ImageRenamed += OnImageRenamed;
```

The following code is the custom event I would like to raise when applyBtn_Click is fired.

```
public delegate void ImageRenamedEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e);

public event ImageRenamedEventHandler ImageRenamed;

protected virtual void OnImageRenamed()
{
    if (ImageRenamed != null)
        ImageRenamed(this, EventArgs.Empty);
}

private void applyBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // do something
    OnImageRenamed();
}
```

Comment: The handler MUST match the delegate.  `OnImageRenamed` has no parameters, but your delegate requires a method with `object sender, EventArgs e` as paramters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a custom delegate if you're seeking attachment of a method with an `(object,EventArgs)` signature, just use

```
public event EventHandler ImageRenamed;
```

and do away with that delegate definition

Also, you can look at changing the event invoke

```
protected virtual void OnImageRenamed(EventArgs e)
{
    EventHandler eh = ImageRenamed;
    eh?.Invoke(this, e);
}
```

(And call that with EventArgs.Empty)

Caching it into a local variable thus could help prevent potential issues if the handler is removed in the small window of time between using `if` to determine if it should be invoked and actually invoking it

If the same event will be raised for multiple different images being renamed, consider providing an EventArgs that informs the receiver which image was renamed.

---

> I've placed this inside the Form1 constructor:

Also worth pointing out you seem to have gone wonky here. The OnImageRenamed method invokes the event and is called by the code originating the event. Classes that raise events may do so via a OnXxx method (but they don't have to)

It's not intended to be the method that *handles* the event. You'd do something more like:

```
this.ImageRenamed += <press the TAB key twice>
```

and VS would do something like this for you:

```
  this.ImageRenamed = Form_ImageRenamed;

} 

private void Form_ImageRenamed(object sender, EventArgs e){
  throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

You replace that NIE with the code you want to run when an image is renamed

Also worth noting that you don't really need the form to handle its own event, because it knows it's occurring. It's more typical to have something like an instance of a button (a self contained class) that you use on your form and attach one of your form's methods to its click event; the method that handles the event (in your form) is thus external to the class raising it (Microsoft's button). You could perhaps have another form that has the instance of the form that does the renaming and do e.g.:

```
renamerForm.ImageRenamed += ...
```

this way when renaming occurs in foreign form `renamerForm` a method in the local form is invoked. The `sender` will be `renamerForm`

---

Internally, consider an `event` to be little more than a list of methods (all with the same signature) that are invoked in any order when the event is raised. You append some method to the list with `+=` and it will be accepted as long as it's signature matches. The following is also valid:

```
ImageRenamed += (s,e) => MessageBos.Show("The image was renamed");
```

Comment: It works without delegate definition! Thank you. You mentioned passing information around with EventArgs, that means defining a new class derived from EventArgs, right? I like your explanation of thinking events as a list of methods to be invoked, that really clarified why there is a +=.

Comment: Yes, you would probably derive from EventArgs and then use the built in `EventHandler<YourEventArgs>` - see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.eventhandler-1?view=net-6.0 - you'd have `public event EventHandler<ImageRenameEventArgs> ImageRenamed;` and a handler method like `private void Form_ImageRenamed(object sender, ImageRenamedEventArgs e){`, and your derived class would have some extra props etc

Answer (score 0):

You have almost done. Your OnImageRenamed needs some parameters:

```
    protected virtual void OnImageRenamed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (ImageRenamed != null)
            ImageRenamed(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
```